# Is it possible to overwrite and use the same value in multiple build.sbt files?

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I have the following dummy project structure:

```
|───employee-uService
|   ├───backend
|   |    ├───employee-api
|   |        ├───project
|   |        ├───src
|   |        │   └───main
|   |        │       ├───protobuf
|   |        │       └───scala
|   |        ├───build.sbt
|   ├───build.sbt
|───build.sbt (root project build)
```

The build.sbt in the employee-api contains project definition with the  `.settings(scalapbSettings("."))` setting.
The `scalapbSettings` function sets up the proto source folder like:

```
val protoSources = PB.protoSources in Compile := Seq(file(s"$projectFolder/src/main/protobuf"))
```

Where the projectFolder is a parameter of the function.

The build.sbt one level higher in the hierarchy (employee-uService) defines employee-api and the respective impl project and aggregates them, while the root build aggregates the ...-uService projects.

Depending on the project I'm compiling, the given string parameter for the `scalapbSettings` function has to change to represent the proper path. (e.g.: in the root it has to be `employee-uService/backend/employee-api` while when running the api compile, it's `.`.

How could I pass a value to the function call that could be overwritten in the different build.sbt files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the directory structure you described (protos are under `src/main/protobuf` in each project), you don't need to set `PB.protoSources` for each project since that is the default. However, if you wanted to specify it explicitly, and allow users to override, you could have in your `scalapbSettings` function the following line:

```
val protoSources = PB.protoSources in Compile := Seq(
    file((sourceDirectory in Compile).value / projectFolder))
```

Then projectFolder should be relative to `src/main` (and can have default value `"protobuf"` of)

Tip: in an SBT shell you can type, `protocSources` to see what is the value of this settings for each project.